# Compose "Insert...Select...Where" query

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to compose a query using Slick 3.0, but can't seem to figure it out.

The equivalent SQL is "insert into SavedMail select * from Inbox where Inbox.id = 1"

```
val mailTable = TableQuery[Tables.Inbox]
val savedMailTable = TableQuery[Tables.Savedmail]
val select = mailTable.filter(_.id === msgId)
```

I'm stuck on how to do the insert now.  Help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution I've come up with.  Perhaps there's a way to not use forceInsertQuery, but hey, this works.

```
val mailTable = TableQuery[Tables.Inbox]
val savedMailTable = TableQuery[Tables.Savedmail]

val select = mailTable.filter(_.id === msgId).map(c => (c.id, c.touserid, c.fromuserid, c.mailtype, c.subject, c.msg, c.postdate))
val q = savedMailTable.map(c => (c.id, c.touserid, c.fromuserid, c.mailtype, c.subject, c.msg, c.postdate)) forceInsertQuery select
```