# slick 3.0 select then insert

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I want to insert a new row with different status value if that row exists and return the new instance as `Some` to the caller. If it does not exist, nothing happens and return `None`. What I have is

```
 def revoke(name: String, issueFor: String): Future[MyLicense] = {
   val retrieveLicense = slickLicenses.filter(l => l.name === name && l.issueFor === issueFor).
  sortBy(_.modifiedOn.desc).result.headOption
   val insertLicense = for {
     licenseOption <- retrieveLicense
   } yield {
     licenseOption match {
       case Some(l) => Some(slickLicenses += l.copy(status = RevokedLicense))
       case None => None
   }
 }
 db.run(insertLicense).map {r => 
   r.map { dbLicense => MyLicense(dbLicense.name, dbLicense.status)
 }
```

}

How do I fix this?

**Edit 1**

I changed the code to

```
override def revoke(name: String, issueFor: String): Future[String] = {
  val retrieveLicense = slickLicenses.filter(l => l.name === name && l.issueFor === issueFor).
  sortBy(_.modifiedOn.desc).result.headOption
  val insertLicenseAction = for {
    l <- retrieveLicense
    newLicense <- slickLicenses += l.get.copy(status = RevokedLicense)
} yield newLicense
  db.run(insertLicenseAction).map(_ => name)
```

}

Hence, the question changes to how do I get the instance I insert into the database? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compose "Insert...Select...Where" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31347462/compose-insert-select-where-query)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did finally,

```
override def revoke(name: String, issueFor: String): Future[String] = {
val retrieveLicense = slickLicenses.filter(l => l.name === name && l.issueFor === issueFor).
    sortBy(_.modifiedOn.desc).result.headOption
val insertLicenseAction = for {
  l <- retrieveLicense
  _ <- l.map(x => slickLicenses += x.copy(status = RevokedLicense, 
             modifiedOn = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())))
    .getOrElse(DBIO.successful(l))
} yield ()
db.run(insertLicenseAction).map(x => name)}
```