# Scala+Slick 3: Inserting the result of one query into another table

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

This question is about slick 3.0 or 3.1 (I am flexible about that)

I have an intermediate query which I process with `map`, `for`, etc. to obtain the result I want. In the end I have a

```
val foo: DBIOAction[Seq[MySchema.Bar], NoStream, Effect.Read]
```

Now I have a `val bar: TableQuery[MySchema.Bar]` and I want to insert foo in to it.

If foo would be a `Seq` I could simply do `bar ++= foo`, but it is not.

The only way I found is to materialize the result by awaiting it. Like this

```
val query = (bar ++= Await.result(db.run(foo), Duration.Inf))
```

Obviously `query` needs to be run at some point with `db.run`. But now I have two DB-runs. Wouldn't it be better to have everything in a single run?

**Is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: `bar += foo` ?   But you would still have to `db.run` it regardless of whether it's `+=` or `++=`... (?)

Comment: I think ++= with side-effects was the slick2 api, while the slick3 is more functional, so it requires you to explicitly do a `db.run`

Comment: Yes the result of ++= is now a query that needs to be run. I edited the question in this point. But I have to do two db.run calls for this task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compose "Insert...Select...Where" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31347462/compose-insert-select-where-query)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DBIOAction` has `map`/`flatMap` functions, so you can write something like

```
val insertAction = foo.flatMap(bar ++= _)
```

The `insertAction` will be of type `DBIOAction[Int, NoStream, Effect.Write]` or something like that (I'm not entirely sure about `Int` and the effect), then you can run it on the DB as any `DBIOAction` using `db.run`; what you then get is a future of the overall query and insert result.

Comment: The `flatMap` does the trick. In the end I have only one DBIOAction left that I need to run. I have run into another thing with this topic: When should I do the db.run()? Here is an example `val foo = db.run( persons.result.map(_.map {p => tr(td(p.id)) }))` I can do it like this, or I could end the `db.run` part after `.result`. Both methods give me the same `Future`, is there any difference in terms of performance?

Comment: In general you want to work at `DBIO` level as far as possible; when you call `db.run` slick will run as many queries are needed using its own execution context and it will return you the `Future`. I think that there is a potential difference in performance if you do so as slick will optimise the usage of threads with respect to DB access.

Answer (score 4):

The questions was already answered but I came here looking for a different solution, so maybe this will be helpful to other people.

As @Aldo says, we want to work at the DBIO level as far as possible, but I would go further and say you should work at the `Query` level as far as possible, as this compiles to a single sql statement that can be sent to the database.

For example, an insert from a select should be compile to a `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT...`. If you use multiple DBIOS using `flatMap`, like suggested, this will be compiled into a `SELECT`, the values will be brought to memory and then an `INSERT` statement will be compiled, interpolating the values in a string and this new query will be sent to the database. In reality this can be much slower if your select returns many results, and it can drain your memory in the worst case.

So to compile something like this into a single query you can write:

```
val bar: TableQuery[MySchema.Bar]

val foo: Query[MySchema.Bar, Bar, Seq]

val insert: DBIO[Int] = bar.forceInsertAll(foo)
```